# Windows Azure: Multiple file asynchronous upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am trying to upload multiple files asynchronously (async and await) on Windows Azure from an C# MVC web app. Just starting with MVC and windows azure so any examples to get me started will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC the files are being cached by ASP.NET for you.

The controller code is simple:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async ActionResult DoStuffWithFilesFoo()
    {
        foreach (HttpPostedFile file in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Cast<HttpPostedFile>())
        {
            await file.InputStream.ReadAsync ... // do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** this is pretty naive example. You want in real production code to deal with empty files, use the file name from the HttpPostedFile etc.